# How to set proxy for application running in IBM WebSphere

Tags: proxy, websphere, websphere-8

There are multiple enterprise applications running on IBM WebSphere 8.5

For one of our application, we want to set proxy level settings. 
I know we can set proxy level on application server level by going to JVM Custom properties and setting http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort.

How can I set proxy level settings for single application on a server ?
Any help will be appreciated.

For example - **employee-soap-services-0_1_0_war** is my application which I want to run with proxy. Attached is the screen of all application in server.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you told http.proxyHost setting is at JVM level and will have impact for every applications running on that JVM.
If your requirement is to route all the webservices calls through proxy, why cant you make the web services endpoint URL the *address of a proxy server accessible over HTTP* and route the request from their to the actual endpoint URL?

For example,

```
Your application ---> http://proxyserver.com:333/app=employee-soap ---> http://employee-soap-services-actual-endpoint/
```